# React Native - Explanation of folders and files

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm new to react native and I've gone through the tutorial but no where does it explain the file and folder structures. I'm confused as to what MainActivity.java does. In addition, say I want to implement Google sign in functionality, should I add another folder in the android folder called signin and put files in there (such as another MainActivity.java, etc.)? In other words, should all the changes and additions made to the app be made in the existing files.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't learnt checked about ReactNative yet.. but by asking `MainActivity.java` sounds to me like sth natively from Android... you may want to checkout Android Developer's Guide?

Comment: That looks helpful. To maybe give more information to my question, you see how here in google-services android folder
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android
they have a folder for signin and then they have other folders as well. Each of these folders have their own MainActivity.java (or some variation of it). Do I need to do this as well? For each thing I implement I add another folder?

Comment: You may want to understand the basis of Android first: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html; the build system is using gradle, after that you may want to check how gradle works: http://gradle.org/

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have the answer